# How to make Visual studio Remote debugger 2017 and 2019 both work on a same computer?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, remote-debugging, visual-studio-2019

VS2017 remote debugger had been working well until some developer replaced it with VS2019 version.
I know them can both work on the same computers since they use different ports (4022 and 4024).
On this computer I already shut down the remote debugger 2019, and ran debugger 2017. It prompts such message:

> Unable to configure this computer to allow remote debugging. The
>   system cann't find the path specified.

[image]

I don't know why.

Answer (score 1):

Just turning-off the firewall solved the problem.